# Source: 'tok_visa' in Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get Stripe going, and I'm almost there but there is one confusing thing. The `source: 'tok_visa'` part. It looks like it can be 'tok_mastercard', 'bank_account' and so forth. The problem is: How am I supposed to know which one to use? The docs say "obtained with Stripe.js", which is cool, but I cannot find where exactly this comes from.

Can anyone explain? That's the only confusing part so far.

Here's my code in Node so far:

```
router.post('/charge', (req, res, next) => {
    var amount = 10000; // in cents
    stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.email,
        source: req.body.token
    }).then(customer => {
        req.user.stripeId = customer.id;
        req.user.save();
        stripe.charges.create({
            amount,
            description: "Charge for the example",
            currency: 'cad',
            source: , // obtained with Stripe.js
            customer: customer.id,
        })
    }).then(
        charge => res.render("payment/charge", {
            title: "Payment report",
            user: req.user
        })
    ).catch(e => console.log(e));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fetching the token using `req.body.token` which means you have already implemented the logic to tokenize client-side. Once the customer is created, you can create a charge by simply passing the customer id `cus_XXXX` in the `customer` parameter of the Create Charge [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).

Comment: So I do not need the `source: ...` at all?

Comment: Not if you charge the default source on the customer no which is the case here.